# After uncommenting a block of code in NERD_commenter, it's improperly indented

Tags: vim, plugins, indentation

I have some python code:

```
     _name = "football.player"
     _description = "Football Player"
     def age_calc(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
```

When I comment it by pressing `,cc` in NERD_commenter, it looks like this:

```
     _name = "football.player"
#     _description = "Football Player"
#     def age_calc(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
```

But after uncommenting, using `,cu` it looks like this:

```
     _name = "football.player"
    _description = "Football Player"
    def age_calc(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
```

Why does this uncommented block appear displaced by 1 space rather than at its original position? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: Because commenting inserts a hash at the beginning. There's nothing to fix.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I think the problem is that "NERD_commenter" appears to be doing the wrong thing after uncommenting.

Comment: 2 Cat Plus Plus. I don`t understand you. What 'hash' do you mean? I want to know why when I comment, it replace text by 1 space, but when I unkomment it, NERD replace it back by 2 spaces

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with nerdcommenter

Answer (score 0):

It could be happening because you're using 5 spaces. What is your tabstop / shiftwidth set to? It might be trying to indent it to a logical, standard (4) spaces, instead of an insane (5) space amount.

If you really want to use 5 spaces for a tab (you don't) you can do `:set shiftwidth=5` and `:set tabstop=5` and `:set et` if you don't have it